# Getting error message on installing Android Apk "App Not Installed" in TFS built Android APK

Tags: android, continuous-integration, android-install-apk

Getting error message(App Not Installed) on installing apk to Android device. This apk is generated by TFS build process(Build - gradlew, signing apk) however the local machine signed apk generated by Android studio installs fine. I am seeing two RSA files in META-INF folder after unzipping apk. Not sure this is the reason for not getting installed. I will appreciate any assistance.
Android 10(API 29)
TargetSdkVersion 29

Comment: check TFS build logs for any issues occurred during the whole process.

Comment: TFS build process completes without any error and creates apk file.

Comment: have you mentioned the buildflavor properly in the TFS build commands ?

Comment: Yes, I have. The build process works fine. I am getting this issue after updating to Android 10 from Android 7. I also tried changing encrypting algorithm on signing key step but no success. Is possible to have two RSAs and two RF files in META-INF folder of apk?

Comment: you mean CERT.RSA ?

Comment: check if you have multiple CERT.RSA in local built apk as well.

Comment: yes. I have CERT.RSA and there is an another RSA file signed by keystore.

Comment: please try to do the same exact commands used in TFS to run in the local machine, not via IDE. see the output